# Can you cross the bridge?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

If

> C = 5
>   N = 2
>   R = 4
>   W = 1
>   P = 9
>   A = 4
>   D = 0
>   G = 7
>   M = 2

Then

> B = ?

Hint : added some lines

Comment: B is equal to the answer the OP intended

Comment: @North no kidding. To Soltius - is modular division involved?

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem!

Comment: @Brandon_J and Dr Xorile : No modular division or chinese remainder theorem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: some of these letters have much more than a single solution.

> We just use basic topology of the symbols and see if they correspond: holes, tails, their connections and etc. The classes of letters presented are: 
>  Just a line as in {C, 5, N, 2, W, 1, G, 7, M } 
> Circle with a tail as in { P, 9 } 
>  Circle with two tails as in {R, A, 4} 
>  Just circle as in {D, 0}.

With that said, B definitely equals

> eight.

BONUS QUESTION FOR CREATOR: 
 What makes me believe that

> POLO equals 0.06?

Comment: thought it would be something visual

Comment: I would say W=3 under these rules, no? And surely M and W would be the same, at least?

Comment: @hexomino I might have been unclear, but by my set of rules M=W=3=2, so you're correct as well.

Comment: How to prove $2 = 3$... @ThomasBlue XD +1

Comment: Good job ! To be more precise, the "equal" sign indicated that values on each sign were related by a homeomorphism : You can read more about it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology, but it basically means that if you squish and pull stuff on the LHS without changing the general toplogy (holes stay holes, etc), you can get the RHS (like a donut can change into a mug).

Comment: A famous historical applicaion of topology is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Bridges_of_K%C3%B6nigsberg, hence the title.

Comment: Still got to work out the POLO now... ;)

Answer (score 6):

If a person wants a cool party, what will he say.

> Wanna rocking party in big hall

Remove all vowels to get

> WNN RCKNG PRTY N BG HLL

Given are the position of letters in which they first appear in this sentence.

> B = 14

This is the answer.

Comment: Is that.. a well-known phrase? o.O (welcome btw!)

Comment: No, I just constructed it :P

Comment: +1 for fun ;) but incorrect of course. added new lines as a hint